# msi installer for playframework 2.3.x

Tags: java, wix, playframework-2.3, wix3.5

I want to make an msi installer for my application, I am using playframework 2.3.0 and trying as per the configuration doc.

I added the plugin in plugin.sbt file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.1")
```

I have istalled wixtoolset as per the documentation from

https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102

and from console I am trying command,

activator dist windows:package-bin

but the command throwing error

```
error CNDL0006 : The Product/@Name attribute's value cann
ot be an empty string.  If you want the value to be null or empty, simply remove
 the entire attribute.
```

followed by

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run WIX compilation to wixobj...
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.windows.WindowsPlugin$$anonfun$windowsSetti
ngs$14.apply(WindowsPlugin.scala:81)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.windows.WindowsPlugin$$anonfun$windowsSetti
ngs$14.apply(WindowsPlugin.scala:69)
        at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
        at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (windows:packageBin) Unable to run WIX compilation to wixobj...
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 8, 2014 3:44:15 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

As of *"com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.8.0-M1"*, you need to explicitly set

```
  packageSummary in Windows := "*name*",
  packageDescription in Windows := "*description*",
```

unfortunately.